# Log entire HTML element not just outer selector?

Tags: javascript

Say I have a simple list:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="/page1">Item 1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/page2">Item 2</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

If I loop over the list and log out each item it seems that only the li is being logged, not the HTML within it.

```
var items = document.querySelectorAll("li");
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
   console.log(items[i]);
}
```

Is there a way to log the entire element, including the link and text?

Comment: You should see a little arrow next to each logged `<li>` - click the arrow and it will expand in the console to show the full contents of the element.

Comment: do you want to loop through each `li` and `a`?

Comment: what exactly are you needing to accomplish?

Comment: The output of *console.log* is implementation dependent. What browser are you using and what do you want to see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.outerHTML` to get the `html` string representation of the element, which includes string representation of child nodes of the element

```
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
   console.log(items[i].outerHTML);
}
```

You can also iterate `.childNodes` of `item[i]`

```
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
   console.log(items[i]);
   for (var j = 0; j < items[i].childNodes.length; j++) {
     console.log(items[i].childNodes[j]);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this working code

```js
window.onload = function () {
        var items = document.querySelectorAll("li");
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            console.log(items[i].innerHTML);
        }
    }
```

```html
 

<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="/page1">Item 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/page2">Item 2</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```